# Retrieve a specific field and value from Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have python dictionary as below.

```
{'AA': Val(customer='AA', dc='x1),
'BB': Val(customer='BB', dc='x2),
'CC': Val(customer='CC', dc='x1)
}
```

I need to create a dataframe which can have two columns as
Customer_Key (value from Key in dictionary)
Customer_Val (value from Val field but only capturing what comes after dc

Desired Output

| Key | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| AA | x1 |
| BB | x2 |
| CC | x1 |

I tried multiple things to capture key and specific field from val but it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Could you share the code you've tried so far?

Comment: We do not know if your `Val` class allows access to the `dc=...` value - beside that your code is Invalid python and would result in SyntaxErrors. [edit] and  fix please - add the Val() class as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd


class Val:
    def __init__(self, customer, dc):
        self.customer = customer
        self.dc = dc


dct = {
    "AA": Val(customer="AA", dc="x1"),
    "BB": Val(customer="BB", dc="x2"),
    "CC": Val(customer="CC", dc="x1"),
}

df = pd.DataFrame([{"KEY": v.customer, "VAL": v.dc} for v in dct.values()])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  KEY VAL
0  AA  x1
1  BB  x2
2  CC  x1
```

Comment: How do you know that `Val` is using `dc` for storing that value verbatim under that attribute name?  Could be used to create somehting composit, could be not stored at all or "private"ly so you do not have access from the outside ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the key, I simply read the dictionary value and save as df which worked

```
df_customer  = pd.DataFrame(dict.values())
```